# Getting data to local state

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-hooks, react-redux

I understand that is incorrect based on searches from StackOverflow to attach the global state to local state using Redux.
Still, I need it to work like this because I can only see data right after refreshing the screen, and this does not meet the requirements.

I am getting the data using:

```js
const { device } = useSelector((state) => state.device);
const [filteredList, setFilteredList] = useState();

useEffect(() => {
  dispatch(devices());
}, []);
```

And setting the device here:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  var filteredData = FilterDevicelocation(device);
  setFilteredList(filteredData);
}, [selectedDevicelocation]);
```

See one of the attempts to make it work:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  dispatch(devices());
  setFilteredList(device);
}, []);
```

Comment: 1. `device` is a selector, not an action. 2. You shouldn't store data from redux in state.

Comment: Can you please provide more information, thanks

Comment: https://redux-toolkit.js.org/tutorials/quick-start

Comment: Based on it, I must updated: const { device } = useSelector((state) => state.device.device);
because i have my slice is : const deviceSlice = createSlice({
  name: "device",
  initialState: {
    device: null,
    loading: false,
  },
but i receive TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'device' of '(0 , react_redux__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.useSelector)(...)' as it is null.